# How to Use an External JAR Offline in a Maven Project for Servlets Without Internet Access?

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G40Rx.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G40Rx.png

click above to get that photo,

Hello Everyone, I seek your assistance with a Maven project that involves servlets. As depicted in the attached photo, I have created a Maven project and included an external JAR file in the Libraries ( similar to how we add a MySQL JAR file in basic Java or JDBC projects. ) In this case, I'm using a downloaded JAR file on my computer, specifically poi-ooxml-lite.jar in Maven project. My objective is to restrict the internet access for this External jar file, which is showen in photo, using it offline within my project, excluding Maven Dependencies. Ultimately, I plan to convert this project into a WAR file for deployment on a VPS.

Can someone guide me on how to block internet access for this external JAR file while still using it in my project?

Could anyone provide guidance or advice on how to disable internet access for this particular external JAR file?

Thank you in advance for your help.

and second problem is that, How to upload image directly on stackoverflow without using these type of link which is automatically provided my stackoverflow.

Comment: Setup an internal repository manager (proxy) for example Nexus and that's it...

Comment: Don't ask many questions at once. The second question is related to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Use offline in what way? Be more specific.

Comment: aled: Maven depends on Internet. Maven will not be able to download JARs when offline. See abovelinked dupe where you can put manually downloaded JARs in an Eclipse-managed WAR project.